# Delete Built-in Users in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

In our server we have more than one SQL Server instance. If I delete the built-in users from one instance (highlighted users), does it get deleted from the others instance or not?

I want to use only and just only sa user.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You should **AVOID** using the `sa` user if ever possible ....

Comment: Actually, you want to disable and never, ever use `sa`, using only and just only the other specific, restricted users. `BUILTIN\Users` is the group that contains all users. The `NT Service` accounts are actually the acounts of SQL Server's own services. `SYSTEM` means that someone was lazy and set a service or web app to run under the all-powerfull `SYSTEM` instead of finding what permissions are actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, You need to delete it from each Instance. But when you delete from Once Instance all the access for that particular user across all the databases in the Instance will be removed along with it.